# Convert C# DateTime to LocalTime on client (JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

On the server I am using Yahoo API for getting currencies 
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDGBP=X,USDEUR=X

in the result I am getting `Date` and `Time` and would like to convert it to `DateTime` Object so I can later convert it to Local time for the clients

I did it with the following

```
DateTime d = dateOnly.Add(timeOnly.TimeOfDay);
```

I now want to convert it to Local Time on the clients (Javascript)

I tried on the client

```
var d = new Date(d + " UTC");
alert(d.toString());
```

**Edit** d value is `2015-04-06T12:32:00`

but getting error `Invalid Date`

Comment: take a look at Datetime.Parse

Comment: Well what is `data[1].DateTime` in the result? You haven't told us anything about how the `DateTime` is being represented to the client...

Comment: Jon, d is the result returned, I have modified my answer (it is a DateTime object)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your code to form an ISO 8601 string correctly.

```js
var d = new Date(d + "Z");
```

Screenshot from Chrome debug console:

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, you could ensure the `Z` was added by your .NET code by making sure the `.Kind` of your `DateTime` value was set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

For example:

```csharp
d = DateTime.SpecifyKind(d, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Or better yet, you can just parse it as UTC to begin with.

```csharp
string dateOnly = "4/6/2015";
string timeOnly = "11:32pm";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOnly + " " + timeOnly,
    "M/d/yyyy h:mmtt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

This is probably the safest way.  Now the kind will already be UTC, and the `Z` will already be in place.

Comment: Also worth noting, that particular API doesn't appear to be returning correct values.  I ran it just now, and it has the time a full hour ahead of the current UTC time.  My guess is they are converting from a local time zone to UTC on their end and not accounting for DST in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  I am assuming Yahoo CSV is in US format (*m/d/yyyy*)... If not, you need to fix the how the month and date are extracted in **fixYahooDate**...

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    String.prototype.pad = function(c, l) {
        return (new Array(l + 1).join(c) + this).substr(-l, l);
    };

    function fixYahooDate(aDate) {
        var match = /(\d?\d)\/(\d?\d)\/(\d+)/gi.exec(aDate);
        var m = match[1];
        var d = match[2];
        var y = match[3];    
        var sm = m.pad('0', 2);
        var sd = d.pad('0', 2);    
        var fixedDate = sm + "/" + sd + "/" + y;
        return fixedDate;
    }

    function fixYahooTime(aTime) {
        var match = /(\d?\d):(\d\d)(am|pm)/gi.exec(aTime);
        var h = match[1];
        var m = match[2];
        var a = match[3];
        var sh = h.pad('0', 2);
        var fixedTime = sh + ":" + m + ":00 " + a + " UTC";
        return fixedTime;
    }

    function YahooDateTimeToLocal(aDate, aTime) {
        var s = fixYahooDate(aDate) + " " + fixYahooTime(aTime);
        console.log(s);
        var dt = new Date(s);
        return dt;
    }

    var aDate = "4/6/2015";
    var aTime = "12:29pm";

    var localDt = YahooDateTimeToLocal(aDate, aTime);    
    console.log(localDt.toString());

}());
```